# Local NuGet source + creating packages with FAKE

Tags: f#, nuget, nuget-package, f#-fake, f#-fake-4

I've been trying to configure my local NuGet source so as to put there my own packages. So I created a folder and set up the path in Visual Studio - this works fine.

Currently I've got a problem with creating a package with FAKE. The nupkg file gets successfully created, but when I try to add a reference to it from another project, nothing happens (i.e. VS says the package was successfully added, but I can't see it under the "References").

My example project has the following structure:

```
-- root
   -- MyProject (project type: F# library)
   -- MyProject.Test (Xunit)
   build.bat
   build.fsx
   MyProject.nuspec
   MyProject.sln
```

And I'd like my NuGet package to contain functions defined in MyProject (It doesn't have any additional dependenties, apart from the "traditional" ones as FSharp.Core).
The content of .nuspec file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <metadata xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <id>@project@</id>
    <version>@build.number@</version>
    <authors>@authors@</authors>
    <owners>@authors@</owners>
    <summary>@summary@</summary>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>@description@</description>
    <releaseNotes>@releaseNotes@</releaseNotes>
    @dependencies@
    @references@
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="**\*.*" exclude="**\*.pdb;**\*.xml" />
  </files>
</package>
```

The build.fsx file is quite long, so I'll paste only piece of it, that is responsible for creating a package (shout if more content is needed):

```
let buildDir = @".\build\"
let testDir  = @".\test\"
let deployDir = @".\deploy\"
let nugetDir = @".\nuget\"

Target "CreateNuget" (fun _ ->
    XCopy buildDir  nugetDir

    "MyProject.nuspec"
      |> NuGet (fun p -> 
            {p with               
                Authors = authors
                Project = projectName
                Description = projectDescription
                Version = version
                NoPackageAnalysis = true
                OutputPath = nugetDir
                })
)

Target "Publish" (fun _ ->     
    !! (nugetDir + "*.nupkg") 
      |> Copy deployDir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your files aren't put into the correct target folder in the nuget package, nuget doesn't know you want to reference them.

You need to change your files so that they put the dlls you want to reference into a `lib` folder in your nuget package for example:

```
<files>
   <file src="directory\MyProject.dll" target="lib" /> 
</files>
```

or from FAKE itself:

```
Nuget(
    { p with
          Files = [@"directory\MyProject.dll", Some @"lib", None] })
```

(but if you want to do it from FAKE you'll have to replace the `files` config section in your nuspec file with `@@files@@`.